# Can I run multiplie instances of sqldependency in the same program

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqldependency

I have two threads each running sqldependency against different tables on the same database.  Individually, both listeners work fine, when i run them concurrently, only one listener works. any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Do they use a shared resource? Could this be a deadlock or livelock issue?